# Which rendering approach i should use in NEXT.JS for my usecase ( SSG, SSR or ISR )?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using Next.js with react.js and my webiste has a page called worksheets , on this page we are displaying worksheets for different grade, subject and topics and their subtopics and for that i implemented dynamic routes like [https://example.com/worksheets/[grade]/[subject]/[...topics].js](https://example.com/worksheets/%5Bgrade%5D/%5Bsubject%5D/%5B...topics%5D.js) and we have diffenet Urls to show different content according to grade, subject and topic and their subtopic , we manage this data i mean worksheet data from our admin side so that data also could update or change now i want to use a correct next.js approach for this usecase so it would be good for seo perspective because right now we implementd client side rendering which is not seo friendly

so actually we are using best practices for our worksheeet page but only problem is some data should come in initial load but that data is javascript dependent so bot is not able to crawl it and that piece of content is not getting index , please suggest what we can do in that case